# ionic2 wait for Promise in forEach loop

Tags: foreach, promise, ionic2

```
  var listOfItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  listOfItems.forEach(
    item => {
      this.createTimeout(3000)
      .then(
        () => {
          console.log(item);
        })   
  });

  createTimeout(timeout) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => resolve(null),timeout)
      })   }
```

I want to wait for Promise response 'createTimeout' and then move to next element. Any ideas ?

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers on this topic here on SO. Basically you need to chain your promises in sequence, such as with `listOfItems.reduce((result, num) => result.then(createTimeout(num)), Promise.resolve());`.

Comment: There are at least a hundred dups for this question here on stack overflow - please search and find one.  You can't use `.forEach()` because it's synchronous and won't pause for the next promise.

Comment: @torazaburo thx, it works